# How to create a large selection screen?

Tags: java, android

My app tracks how players at a pokertable play. I give my users the option to save up to 50 players stats in the form of a 'Player' object stored inside a JSON array within sharedPreferences. Allowing the user a way of selecting and loading one of these players has proven difficult.

An alertDialog seems to small, a new activity seems a bit overboard for what is essentially just a large menu and I fear passing my objects to it will prove difficult. A viewFlipper sounds interesting but I've no idea whether it's suitable.

How should I go about doing this? Filling the screen with dozens of buttons is really all I wish to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). It combines the filtering and tidyness of the autocomplete yet displays the names so users don't have to remember them like the ViewFlipper solution.

[image]

Thanks for both answers, they are both good solutions that helped me come to the solution I needed which combines the two.

The autocomplete had the advantage of searching so I could extend the number of players a user can save to my hearts content, it also looked neat but could not easily see the whole list which for poker players was necessary as the names you give when titling your notes are rarely your fellow players name but rather off the cuff nicknames based on their appearance/playing style. Hence using autocomplete the user will have to remember the nicknames they gave which over 50 players and potentially months apart would prove tricky.

Alek Gs solution would avoid that problem but would not be suited large numbers of names or long names for that matter as the buttons would be off fixed sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that creating a new activity for this would be an overkill.  One way to address this would be to have a `GridView` populated with your "buttons" - and the user would select one from the grid by clicking it.  The question is where/how to display this grid.

ViewFlipper is a nice option in my opinion.  The way you would go about it is place your existing layout inside the view flipper, then put the GridView into the ViewFlipper after your existing layout:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/flipper">

    <LinearLayout ...>

        <!-- this is where your main layout goes -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/player_select"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

Then in your activity set up the Adapter for your grid view and the `OnItemClickListener` - to do something when one item is clicked.  Finally somewhere (either in the main layout or in the options menu or elsewhere) provide something to display this grid view.  In the handler code for that action you'd have something like

```
ViewFlipper flip = (ViewFlipper)flip.findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flip.showNext();
```

This would effectively hide your main layout and show the grid instead.  And at the end of your `OnItemClickListener` you'll have

```
ViewFlipper flip = (ViewFlipper)flip.findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flip.showPrevious();
```

This would hide the grid view and navigate back to your main layout.  Feel free to add any animation you like for the transition (e.g. 3G flip animation looks particularly nice).

Answer (score 1):

Try an `AutoCompleteTextView`. Start typing one of the names, and a list of all possible matches pops up.

Screenshot from [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html):

[image]